# Exchange 2013 MX record associated with recipient domain not working

Tags: email, exchange, email-server, exchange-2013

We have been using our e-mail filtering company as a Smart Host for years but now we've switched to doing the filtering locally.

I've tested setting our Send Connector to **MX record associated with recipient domain** but the e-mails don't get delivered until I switch it back to **Route mail through smart hosts**.

Is there some other set up required to get the **MX record associated with recipient domain** option working?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be clear, the setting you are changing is for OUTBOUND email, not inbound.

There should be nothing else required. 
Does your ISP allow outbound SMTP traffic from your server/network?

Try to telnet to port 25 of a remote host and see if you can connect.

Comment: Yes outbound, nothing sends whilst it's set to that. I then change it back to smart host and it all sends?

Comment: You need to go through the tests I have outlined.
It could be that your firewall is only allowing access to the smart host and nothing else, or another block is taking place.

Comment: What server should I test?

Comment: Doesn't matter. As long as it is an MX record host that is outside of your and the ISP network. You aren't sending any email, just confirming the connection, so Google, Office365 or even AOL will be fine.